# Processing Images [Database Design]

Tags: sql, database-design, many-to-many, relational-database, erd

I'm working on an entity relationship diagram , trying to outline an initial structure for a database I'm planning to build in Oracle SQL Developer.

In one part of my database there are two camera entities which take images and send them to another entity called a Field Programmable Gate Array to be processed. Now working out the relationship between these entities there are a number of many to many relationships that occur between these entities.

**These are the two camera entities:**

[image]

These Camera generate images, now conceptually many of these two cameras can create many images, so that is defined as a many to many relationship.

Here is the table I created to link the PK from the MastCam table to with the PK from the MastCam_Images table

[image]

As you can see, this table highlights which of the two MastCams created the specific image related to it

This table highlights the images generated and their specific resolution

[image]

At this point, the images are sent to the FPGA to be processed. Again conceptually, many images in this table can be processed by many of the two FPGA's that are present in the FPGA table.

[image]

At this point the FPGA outputs the processed images

[image]

My main issue here, is that once the images are passed to the FPGA, I lose track of what specific Mastcam images were processed into which specific FPGA processed image.

Would anyone be able to provide a logical solution to my issue?

P.S I'm sorry for inconsistent sizes of the images

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. PS None of the example data is needed for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You want rows where "mastcam image *mi* was processed into processed image *pi*". That table is not expressible in terms of your other tables. So add it. But then your table FPGA/FPGAPI holding rows where "fpga *f* output processed image *pi*" is expressible in terms of the other tables, since it is also rows where "for some *mi* [mastcam image *mi* was processed into processed image *pi* AND mastcam image *mi* was processed by fpga *f*]", which is a projection of the join of the new table & table MIF/PGA.

In the relational model *relations*/*tables* represent business/application relation(ship)s/associations. A table holds the rows that make a true *proposition* (statement) from some *predicate* (statement template) that for base relations is given by the designer and for queries is built from base table predicates & relation operators. The designer must find sufficient predicates/tables to record all data of interest while hopefully minimizing complexity & redundancy.

A cardinality is just one property of a relation(ship)/association. A FK (foreign key) constraint (although incorrectly *called* a "relationship" by pseudo-ER methods) is just fact of a certain kind about a pair of tables.

Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design.